# Getting current signed in user PHP

Tags: php, authentication

I am having the hardest time trying to figure out how to echo the current user in PHP after logging in. I know it's something simple but I can't figure it out. When I do `<?php echo $_SESSION['usersignedin']; ?>` I get "username". Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is what I am using.

**index.php (sign in page)**

```
<?php

require_once('include.php');

$error = '';

$form = (isset(  $_POST['submit']) ?  $_POST['submit'] : null);

$username = (isset(  $_POST['username']) ?  $_POST['username'] : null);

$password = (isset(  $_POST['password']) ?  $_POST['password'] : null);

if( isset($form) ) {

if( isset($username) && isset($password) && $username !== '' && $password !== '' ) {


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE username='$username' and
password='$password';");

if( mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0 ) { //success

$_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;

header('Location: signedin.php');

exit;

} else { $error = "Invalid Username or Password"; }

} else { $error = 'Username and Password not filled out';}

}


?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign In</title>




</head>
<body>



<center><h1>Please sign in.</h1></center> 
<div id="pagewrapper">  <!-- Start pagewrapper div -->


<div id="login_wrapper">
    <div id="login">

        <form action="<?php $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post" >

           <table>

            <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo "$username";?>" /><br /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" /><br /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <td>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
            </td>
<?php

echo "<br /><span style=\"color:red\">$error</span>";

?>

        </form>

    </div>    
</div>  <!-- End login wrapper -->


</div> <!-- End pagewrapper div -->

</body>
</html>
```

**signedin.php (page after signing in)**

```
<?php

require_once('include.php');


if ( !isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) || $_SESSION['logged-in'] !== true) {

header('Location: index.php');

exit;

}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE username='$username' and
password='$password';");

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign in</title>

</head>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


<body>

<body class="home">

    <div id="header">

        <div id="welcome"> 

        <p>Hi, <?php echo $_SESSION['usersignedin']; ?> ! <a href="logout.php">logout</a></p>

        </div>


        <div id="links">

<ul>

</ul> 


        </div>
 </div>

        <div id="content">
&nbsp;


<div id= "stuff">


<h3 class="stuffheader">Header</h3>

<p> Text </p>



            </div>




            <div id= "stuff">


<h3 class="stuffheader">Header</h3>


            </div>




</div>




</body>
</html>
```

**include.php (DB Stuff)**

```
<?php

session_start();

$host = "localhost";

$username = "root";

$password = "root";

$db = "intranet";


@mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die ("error");

@mysql_select_db($db) or die("error");


?>
```

Comment: Consider to use a MVC framework

Comment: Where are you setting `$_SESSION['usersignedin'];`?

Comment: As @relentless said, you never assign `$_SESSION['usersignedin']` the value of the username. Something like `$_SESSION['usersignedin'] = $username;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the code, it doesn't seem you've actually set `$_SESSION['usersignedin'];` (I don't know how it got the value 'username'). To set it you could modify the following:

```
if( mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0 ) { //success
    $_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
    header('Location: signedin.php');
    exit;
} else { 
    $error = "Invalid Username or Password"; 
}
```

To this:

```
if( mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0 ) { //success
    $ui = mysql_fetch_object($sql);
    $_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
    $_SESSION['usersignedin'] = $ui->username;
    header('Location: signedin.php');
    exit;
} else { 
    $error = "Invalid Username or Password"; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Works perfect.  I am not sure why people marked this as too specific and not likely to help others. I was asking how to echo a logged in users, username.